# Why is my very small number not being stored precisely?

Tags: raku

In an [answer on StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/405/632), I showed that Perl 6 avoids the calculation errors of many other languages because it keeps track of the numerators and denominators. That is to say, decimal numbers are actually represented as Ratios. However, it does make a small error with very small numbers:

```
> 0.000000000000000000071.nude.perl
(71, 1000000000000000000000)
> 0.0000000000000000000071.nude.perl
(71, 10000000000000000000000)
> 0.00000000000000000000071.nude.perl
(71, 99999999999999991611392)
```

Is this something that will be fixed in future versions?

I get the same answers using `perl6/rakudo-star-2015.09` and `perl6/rakudo-star-2015.11`

Comment: That should be an error, or converted to a Num. Rat is supposed to only have up to `uint64.Range.max` denominator. 18446744073709551615 (20 digits) If you want a Rational with that big of a denominator, use a FatRat. `FatRat.new(71,10²³)` or `71.FatRat / 10²³`

Comment: @BradGilbert: +1 - I did not yet see your comment when I wrote my answer :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denominators are supposed to be limited to 64-bit - you need a `FatRat` to go beyond that.

However, said limit does not appear to be enforced in current Rakudo: If you do so manually, it will happily construct your number via `Rat.new(71, 10**23)`.

My guess would be you have uncovered a bug in the handling of rational literals, <del>but it might only trigger in code that is not future-proof anyway.</del>

*edit:* It is possible to use angle brackets to get an [allomorphic value](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Allomorphic_value_semantics), and this produces the correct value. In fact, regular rational literals are [also specced](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Allomorphic_Rats) to fall back to `RatStr` on overflow.

However, this fallback mechanism does not appear to be implemented in Rakudo.

Comment: Thanks!  Thinking in terms of DWIM, wouldn't we want Perl 6 to just figure out that we need FatRat and use it or is there another underlying issue?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms: Perl6 literals in general are monomorphic and don't DWIM; however, there's the angle brackets syntax `<0.5>` that does so and likely could be extended to return a `FatRatStr` instead of a `RatStr` when appropriate

Comment: Sweet! `<0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000071>.nude.perl` gives `(71, 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)`

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms:\o/ personally, I expected that both kinds of literal would re-use the same codepath and would show identical behaviour; *insert saying about making assumptions at your convenience*

Comment: The specification is the testsuite known as [roast](https://github.com/perl6/roast/). Everything else is just conjecture.